# Magento with APC enabled - can not download product files

Tags: magento, download, apc, php

I have a Magento (CE version 1.9) site run on NGINX + PHP_FPM. Everything worked well.

I installed and configured APC (3.1.15-dev) and it worked well BUT there is just a problem: Customers loged-in and download downloadable product file and it does not return `product.zip` file, instead php file with octet stream.

When I change `apc.enabled=1` to `;apc.enabled=1` in `apc.ini`, restart PHP_FPM, then when customer download the file, it return the correct file `product.zip`.

Did anyone get this problem? Please help me since I can not found the solutions.

**apc.ini**

```
extension = apc.so
apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_size=64M
apc.shm_strings_buffer=0
apc.ttl=7200
apc.user_ttl=7200
apc.mmap_file_mask=/tmp/apc.XXXXXX
```

**Magento local.xml**

```
<cache>
    <backend>apc</backend>
    <prefix>MySITE_</prefix>
</cache>
```

Many Thanks!